# How to solve this $(1+x)^{-86}+26555.9x-1 = 0$?

Tags: polynomials

How to solve this problem?
$$(1+x)^{-86}+26555.9x-1 = 0$$
Calculus allowed.

Comment: Use Newtons Method for a numerical solution.

Comment: Yes, I tried but I am not sure for initial guess.

Comment: This is not a polynomial. You will need numerical methods.

Comment: 0 Is a obvious solution, you might try something larger.

Comment: Afaik there are 3 solutions, 0 is obvious and 2 are around -1, and they are probably _not_ determinable exactly (with square-formulas).

Comment: Can you please enhance the OP with examples of your attempted solutions?

Comment: You could try -0.086 as an initial guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative has only one zero; and there is the singularity at $x=-1$, so there can be at most 3 solutions, by Rolle's Theorem.
For the two near $x=-1$, let $x=-1+y$, then $y\approx26555.9^{-1/86}\approx\pm0.9$ so they are nearer -1.9 and -0.1.
Now $y\approx(26555.9*1.9)^{-1/86}$ and $y\approx(26555.9*0.1)^{-1/86}$, which might be close enough for Newton's Method.

Comment: That is right Michael!

Answer (score 1):

You can expand the left factor with the generalized binomial theorem, which in this case yields an infinite power series + 1. This one drops out as you have a - 1  on the right, and you will end up with an infinite power series again that should equal zero. So that implies one of the solutions is x = 0, however there could be other solutions.